# Formatting of Wordpress Category Descriptions

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. Is it possible to add further formatting to the category descriptions:

[image: Categories]

The description is shown on the theme I am using:

[image: Categories]

It would be nice if I could embolden some words and / or assign a hyperlink to certain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Allow HTML in Category Descriptions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/) plugin which disables filters that strip out all but the most basic formatting tags.